# input submit is not working in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

the Form and input in the Google Chrome browser do not work properly, but when I open the Firefox browser, it works properly. The design structure is completely crashed in the Google Chrome browser. The height of the form and the button is too high. Please help me.

```
<form id="mc4wp-form-1" class="mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-380" method="post" data-id="380" data-name="cdb_subscribe_form">
<div class="mc4wp-form-fields">
    <div class="newsletter-form">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="enter email" required="">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<label style="display: none !important;">Leave this field empty if you're human:
    <input type="text" name="_mc4wp_honeypot" value="" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off">
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_timestamp" value="1554918468">
<input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_form_id" value="380">
<input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_form_element_id" value="mc4wp-form-1">
<div class="mc4wp-response"></div>
```

```
.newsletter-form {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.newsletter-form:before {
  content: "\f003";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 46px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #c7cedf;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.newsletter-form .form-control {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 44px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.newsletter-form input[type=submit] {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR7C8.png)**

Comment: which version of Chrome are you using? (it ran ok when I put your code in a snippet, but i rolled it back to separate the html/css just for the chrome users). Please add any other css

Comment: i use last version google chrome

Comment: Inversely, make sure the problem is reproducible. I've noticed that Chrome crashes a lot since a major update they did around the beginning of the year, but if you restart the browser and do the exact same thing again, it will work just fine.

Comment: This code can not be correct. Height is too high if you are Accuracy

Answer (score 0):

all css in here

```
        *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.5;
        color: #212529;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    html {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.15;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }

    label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    html,
    body,
    div,
    span,
    applet,
    object,
    iframe,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p,
    blockquote,
    pre,
    a,
    abbr,
    acronym,
    address,
    big,
    cite,
    code,
    del,
    dfn,
    em,
    font,
    ins,
    kbd,
    q,
    s,
    samp,
    small,
    strike,
    strong,
    sub,
    sup,
    tt,
    var,
    dl,
    dt,
    dd,
    ol,
    ul,
    li,
    fieldset,
    form,
    label,
    legend,
    table,
    caption,
    tbody,
    tfoot,
    thead,
    tr,
    th,
    td {
        border: 0;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-style: inherit;
        font-weight: inherit;
        margin: 0;
        outline: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .footer-widgets .widget {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .footer-widgets:first-child.widget,
    .footer-widgets .widget.widget_contacts {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .footer-widgets .footer-widget-col {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:992px) */

    .footer-three-col .footer-widget-col {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
        flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
        max-width: 33.33%;
    }

    .footer-widgets .footer-widgets-inner {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }

    .footer-widgets {
        padding: 6em 0;
    }

    .container,
    .vc-container {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:576px) */

    .container,
    .vc-container {
        max-width: 540px;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:768px) */

    .container,
    .vc-container {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:992px) */

    .container,
    .vc-container {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:1200px) */

    .container,
    .vc-container {
        max-width: 1230px;
    }

    article,
    aside,
    dialog,
    figcaption,
    figure,
    footer,
    header,
    hgroup,
    main,
    nav,
    section {
        display: block;
    }

    article,
    aside,
    details,
    figcaption,
    figure,
    footer,
    header,
    hgroup,
    nav,
    section {
        display: block;
    }

    .site-footer {
        background-color: #222e59;
    }

    .site-footer {
        background-color: #2e3e77;
    }

    .site-footer.footer-color-light {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    }

    .wrap {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .wrap {
        -webkit-transition: all .5s;
        transition: all .5s;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }

    input,
    button,
    select,
    optgroup,
    textarea {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
    }

    button,
    input {
        overflow: visible;
    }

    body,
    *:not(.wp-core-ui) button,
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }

    html,
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Nunito", Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #7d7e7f;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1.75rem;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    body {
        font-family: Raleway;
        color: #7d7e7f;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        color: #6c757d;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }

    button,
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    button,
    input {
        line-height: normal;
    }

    input,
    textarea {
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    }

    input[type='text'],
    input[type='password'],
    input[type='number'],
    input[type='date'],
    input[type='datetime'],
    input[type='datetime-local'],
    input[type='time'],
    input[type='month'],
    input[type='week'],
    input[type='email'],
    input[type='search'],
    input[type='tel'],
    input[type='url'],
    input.input-text,
    select,
    textarea {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-weight: inherit;
        line-height: 1.6;
        outline: 0;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
        border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s;
        transition: all .2s;
    }

    .newsletter-form {
        position: relative;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }

    .newsletter-form .form-control {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        padding-left: 44px;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    }

    button,
    html [type='button'],
    [type='reset'],
    [type='submit'] {
        -webkit-appearance: button;
    }

    button,
    html input[type='button'],
    input[type='reset'],
    input[type='submit'] {
        -webkit-appearance: button;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .btn,
    input[type='button'],
    input[type='reset'],
    input[type='submit'],
    .button,
    .button-secondary,
    .woocommerce_message .button,
    .woocommerce-message .button,
    .event-single-side a.event_register_submit,
    .event_register_submit {
        text-align: center;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 50px;
        padding: 9px 22px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        text-shadow: none;
        line-height: 27px;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .btn-filled,
    .top-bar-cart .dropdown-cart .woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons a:first-child,
    input[type='button'],
    input[type='reset'],
    input[type='submit'],
    .button,
    .button-secondary,
    .woocommerce_message .button,
    .woocommerce-message .button {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #f9a134;
    }

    input[type='button'],
    input[type='reset'],
    input[type='submit'],
    .button,
    .button-secondary,
    .woocommerce_message .button,
    .woocommerce-message .button {
        font-weight: inherit;
    }

    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube,
    .main-sidebar-holder .widget .widget-title::before,
    .page-pagination > span,
    .btn-filled,
    .top-bar-cart .dropdown-cart .woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons a:first-child,
    input[type=button],
    input[type=reset],
    input[type=submit],
    .button,
    .button-secondary,
    .woocommerce_message .button,
    .woocommerce-message .button,
    .studiare-social-links.rounded li a.custom:hover,
    ul.page-numbers .page-numbers.current,
    ul.page-numbers .page-numbers:hover,
    .page-numbers.studiare_wp_link_pages > .page-number,
    .studiare-event-item .studiare-event-item-holder .event-inner-content .date-holder .date::before,
    .studiare-event-item .studiare-event-item-holder .event-inner-content .date-holder .date::after,
    .product-reviews .product-review-title .inner::after,
    .product-reviews-stats .detailed-ratings .detailed-ratings-inner .course-rating .bar .bar-fill,
    .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span,
    .double-bounce1,
    .double-bounce2 {
        background-color: #f9a134;
    }

    .newsletter-form input[type=submit] {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```